# Push changes from Intellij to Bitbucket fails

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am trying to push changes to `Bitbucket` repository branch from `Intellij` and I am receiving the following message.

```
Push failed: fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

I have already installed `bitbucket` IDE plugin provided my credentials as well as public key.
What else am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Git or Mercurial? BitBucket supports both, and this may be an issue with the core VCS.

Comment: Are you using SSH or HTTPS? I saw rumors that using HTTPS instead of SSH may fix this